# Is initializing a signal from another signal allowed?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following VHDL simulation code. It's a minimal example taken from an OSVVM-based `clock_Monitor` verification IP.

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity clock_monitor is
  generic (
    PERIOD_HIGH : time := 5 ns;
    PERIOD_LOW  : time := 5 ns
  );
  port (
    Clock : in  std_logic
  );
end entity;

architecture vip of clock_monitor is
  signal ClockPeriodHigh    : time    := PERIOD_HIGH;
  signal ClockPeriodLow     : time    := PERIOD_LOW;

  signal Period             : time    := ClockPeriodHigh + ClockPeriodLow;
begin
  -- not relevant

end architecture;
```

This code analyzes in:

- Riviera-PRO 2018.2
- GHDL 0.36-dev
- ModelSim 10.5b

This code causes an error in ModelSim's *pedantic* mode:

> ** Error (suppressible): C:/Training/Git/RGB_LED/lib/Clock/src/clock_Monitor.vhdl(18): (vcom-1013) Initial value of "Period" depends on value of signal "ClockPeriodHigh".
>   ** Error (suppressible): C:/Training/Git/RGB_LED/lib/Clock/src/clock_Monitor.vhdl(18): (vcom-1013) Initial value of "Period" depends on value of signal "ClockPeriodLow".

Any ideas why this is accepted by the simulators, but reported as error in strict / pedantic modes??

**Edit:**
Code line used to compile with ModelSim:

```
vcom -modelsimini modelsim.ini -2008 -explicit -pedanticerrors -rangecheck -work OSVVM_Clock C:/Training/Git/RGB_LED/lib/Clock/src/clock_Monitor.vhdl
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but can you not define a `constant PERIOD : time := PERIOD_HIGH + PERIOD_LOW` and initialize `signal Period : time := PERIOD`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm using the constant now to be more standard compliant, but I still would like to know why some tools see a problem in that code. Actually, the two generic parameters are passed into complex functions. The results are now stored in constants and used to initialize the three signals.

Comment: verror - "vcom Message # 1013: The value of a signal is not defined until after the design hierarchy is elaborated. Use of the signal name in a declarative item is prohibited because the value is undefined until the entire design has been elaborated. [DOC: IEEE Std 1076-1993 VHDL LRM - 12.3 Elaboration of a declarative part] [DOC: IEEE Std 1076-2008 VHDL LRM - 14.4.1 General]" Also see 12.3.1.4/14.4.2.5 Object declarations, 12.3.1 Elaboration of a declaration/14.4.2.1. Suppressible says they don't agree with other vendors interpretation/usage but can acquiesce.

Comment: See [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183177/question-closed-because-yes-no-answer/183183#183183